# CocoaPods installing ReactiveSwift/ReactiveCocoa incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I’m trying to install ReactiveSwift/ReactiveCocoa in a project and having no luck.  At first I was puzzled over the weird errors Xcode reported about my attempts at ReactiveCocoa code:

[image]

However, further examination indicates that Xcode is building the React, ReactiveSwift, and ReactiveCocoa frameworks but failing to integrate them properly.

[image]

My question is:  How do I fix things so Xcode puts everything together correctly?  I can’t find anything obviously wrong in my Podfile.

```
project ‘CitiTakeHome.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'CitiTakeHome' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for CitiTakeHome
# pod 'ReactiveSwift'
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa'

  target 'CitiTakeHomeTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CitiTakeHomeUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Other, possibly related info:  Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b) running on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Any idea what’s gone wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out pod 'ReactiveSwift'. Uncomment this line and everything will be ok.

Comment: Uncommenting that line changes nothing.

Comment: try this: 
pod 'ReactiveSwift', '~> 3.0'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 7.0'
instead of  pod 'ReactiveSwift'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa',

Comment: There is no problem with pod file, the error may be in your code. Would you please give your code screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what the code looks like:

[image]

Comment: `Signal.merge` should use parentheses rather than curly braces. The list of signals you are merging are parameters.

Comment: That definitely did something.  The code now compiles.  Now I have to hook everything up properly so that new signal does something.  Thanks!

Comment: And now I’ve gotten my code to do what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this an answer?